# java.io.IOException: parseAlgParameters failed: PBE AlgorithmParameters not available, caused when docker container tries to access rabbitmq TLS port

Tags: java, docker, maven, ssl, rabbitmq

I am trying to connect to a RabbitMQ instance through a TLS port from a docker container running a maven spring-boot application client.

Although I already update **java.security** with the line:

*security.provider.10=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider*

And I also added the jar of the **Bouncy Castle** inside the container and installing it through maven, and also adding the dependency to the parent pom of the project. An exception keeps on popping:

```
*java.io.IOException: parseAlgParameters failed: PBE AlgorithmParameters not available*

...

*Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: PBE AlgorithmParameters not available*
```

Before running the Rabbitmq client through a container I ran it locally on a Ubuntu OS and it works fine. (https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html , Example 2)

Docker container is a host enabled container that the .p12 and rabbitstore files are successfully delivered inside the container. The container uses jdk1.8 and successfully connects via the non-TLS port of rabbitmq.

The exception cause is appeared to be in this part of the code:

```
 *char[] keyPassphrase = "lerum".toCharArray();*

 *KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");*

 *ks.load(new FileInputStream("test.p12"), keyPassphrase);*
```

Is there anyone know what it could be off?

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM maven:3.6.0-jdk-8 AS build

COPY /test.p12 test.p12

COPY /certification.pem certification.pem

COPY /jdk-8u241-linux-x64.tar.gz .

COPY /Scripts/install-java.sh .

COPY /jdk-8u241-linux-x64.tar.gz .

COPY /bcprov-ext-jdk15to18-167.jar /docker-java-home/jre/lib/ext/

COPY /java.security /docker-java-home/jre/lib/security/

#installing java

RUN  yes | /install-java.sh -f /jdk-8u241-linux-x64.tar.gz

#environmental variables

RUN export JAVA_HOME=/docker-java-home/jre/lib/ext:$JAVA_HOME

#Bouncy Castle install

RUN mvn install:install-file -Dfile=bcprov-ext-jdk15to18-167.jar -DgroupId=org.bouncycastle -DartifactId=bcprov-jdk15on -Dversion=1.67 -Dpackaging=jar

RUN printf 'lerum\lerum\nyes' | keytool -import -alias server1 -file certification.pem -keystore rabbitstore

RUN mvn clean install

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash","irrelevat.sh"]
```

Comment: `AlgorithmParameters PBE` should be provided by the SunJCE provider. Make sure you haven't removed or otherwise disabled that provider. For example before the load do `for(Provider p : Security.getProviders()) System.out.println(p.getName());` PS: why are you COPYing the jdk tar twice?

Comment: Dave, thanks for the fast response. The ouput is as such: 

container |SUN 

container | SunRsaSign 

container | SunJSSE 

container | SunJGSS 

container | SunSASL 

container | XMLDSig 

container | SunPCSC 

Does that means I am missing the provider SunJCE?

Even though I can see that in the java.security file there is the :  
security.provider.5=com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE


 #BTW for the PS, it was left there from the debugging I changed the workdir in previous versions. Thanks

Comment: Sure looks like it is missing, yes. I notice SunEC is also absent, and BC is not there even though you added it to the file. Can you do the same check at or near startup? Does any of your code or any library you use alter the provider list? Does anything set `java.security.properties` to use a different file?

Comment: I am afraid the output remains the same. I cant seem to locate any library that possibly alters the provider. Also I am positive that the java.security file is used, because when I alter it there are errors that occure. It just cant load the providers...  Is there a way to hardcode the libraries (passing the jars) with a bash script (?) or with any other way? Thanks

Comment: Are you deploying this in FIPS-140-2 secure mode? You can check on your system (if it is a Linux system) by running "sysctl crypto.fips_enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning here after months to report the way i fixed it back then, well in short I changed the whole notion of importing a new security library. Removed the bouncy-castle imports because it was unnecessary after all. Creating the certificates with tls-gen in a folder named Certificates and then modified the Dockerfile adding the following lines in the beginning of the Dockerfile.

```
COPY /Certificates /opt/test/Certificates

RUN keytool -import -alias dockervm -file /opt/test/Certificates/server_certificate.pem -keystore /opt/test/keyStore  -storepass lerum -noprompt
```

Made sure that the files generated by tls-gen are imported in the Rabbitmq configuration in the docker instance (Certificates folder) are also referred in the Rabbitmq configurations file (https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html#enabling-tls). I disabled the tcp listeners for the rabbit and also used TLSv1.3 as the v1.2 was problematic. This solved the problem and served my purpose.